# Is there a way to convert "+" to "-" in URL Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

I am trying to change the paramlinks to include the name of a post in my yii2 application.

> example.com/item/hello+world

to

> example.com/item/hello-world

These are the rules of in my urlmanager in frontend/config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                'item/<title:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => 'item/view',
            ],
        ]
```

Comment: heey, you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: But what is generating the "Hello+world"? All controllers and actions will have "-" if they have more than one word capitalized. This string is probably something you inputted in the link, so you can change it any way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the hello+world is generated by the yii function Url::toRoute(['item/view', 'title' => $model->title]).

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
$hi = 'example.com/item/hello+world';
$hi = str_replace('+', '-', $hi);

echo $hi;
```

like this you can replace what you need replacing with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

output:

> example.com/item/hello-world

The output url you displayed is put in a variable, then i fill in what I want replaced **+**, what should overwrite it is the **-** sign and then store it again in a variable called **$hi** again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the [Url::toRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#toRoute()-detail) method. By default, it will replace empty spaces by a "+". And there is no configuration to change that (at least I did not find).

You could use a `str_replace` like @baboizk mentioned, or, if you want to cover any accents, symbols, etc. You can use [BaseInflector::slug](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseinflector.html#slug()-detail). Example:

```
Url::toRoute(['item/view', 'title' => BaseInflector::slug($model->title)]);
```

But i'm still not sure how your **actionItem** works, because it probably needs to search the model by it's title and you are changing it.